# sql query to convert one column into two based on three different column values in a same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

| equipment_type | machine_num | status | datestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RR | 1 | 9 | 2021-08-20 10:39:36.430 |
| RR | 2 | 1 | 2021-08-20 10:39:36.430 |
| RL | 4 | 2 | 2021-08-20 10:39:36.700 |
| RR | 5 | 0 | 2021-08-20 10:39:36.830 |
| RL | 3 | 2 | 2021-08-20 10:39:37.030 |
| RR | 1 | 3 | 2021-08-20 10:40:36.203 |
| RR | 2 | 2 | 2021-08-20 10:40:36.207 |
| RL | 4 | 1 | 2021-08-20 10:40:37.010 |
| RR | 5 | 3 | 2021-08-20 10:40:37.200 |
| RL | 3 | 3 | 2021-08-20 10:40:37.517 |
| RR | 1 | 1 | 2021-08-20 10:40:38.203 |
| RR | 2 | 1 | 2021-08-20 10:40:38.777 |
| RL | 4 | 1 | 2021-08-20 10:40:39.010 |
| RR | 5 | 1 | 2021-08-20 10:40:39.200 |
| RL | 3 | 1 | 2021-08-20 10:40:39.517 |

There are 2 equipment types, 5 machine nums, 5 statuses and their respective datestamp in the table. If status shows 0 or 9 or 2 then I want that respective datestamp as starttime and again whenever the status shows 3 or 1 for same equipment type and machine num then I want that respective time as endtime.

I want the output like below

| equipment_type | machine_num | datestamp(start time) | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RR | 1 | 2021-08-20 10:39:36.430 | 2021-08-20 10:40:36.203 |
| RR | 2 | 2021-08-20 10:40:36.207 | 2021-08-20 10:40:38.777 |
| RL | 4 | 2021-08-20 10:39:36.700 | 2021-08-20 10:40:37.010 |
| RR | 5 | 2021-08-20 10:39:36.830 | 2021-08-20 10:40:37.200 |
| RL | 3 | 2021-08-20 10:39:37.030 | 2021-08-20 10:40:37.517 |

Can anyone help me to write query for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to define groups based on a cumulative sum of 9/0/2 and then aggregate:

```
select equipment_type, machine_num,
       min(datestamp), max(datestamp)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status in (0, 9, 2) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by equipment_type, machine_num order by datestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by equipment_type, machine_num, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0bd69c279eaa850d5b15224f26c1f2ab) is a db<>fiddle.

To be honest, though, your sample results are a simple aggregation that do not follow the rules you specify based on the status:

```
select equipment_type, machine_num,
       min(datestamp), max(datestamp)
from t
group by equipment_type, machine_num;
```

Comment: I am getting the same datestamp in starttime and endtime column.

Comment: I will ask my question more clearly. There are 2 equipment types, 5 machine nums, 5 status and their respective datestamp in the table. If status shows 0 or 9 or 2  for particular equipment type and machine num then I want that respective datestamp as starttime for that respective equipment time and machine num. Afterwards whenever the status shows 3 or 1 for same equipment type and machine num then I want that respective time as endtime.

Comment: Can anyone answer my question please

Comment: @MariappanGanesan . . . I added a version in the answer (and SQL fiddle) that returns the results you specify in the question.  However, it just a simple aggregation query.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you please write the query for that

Comment: I think the sample data which i had mentioned is not accurate as the original data, that's why the results are not coming when i write your query. Is it possible to attach the excel file in the website

Comment: @MariappanGanesan . . . You should ask a new question with appropriate explanation and sample data.  This question has been answered.