# SQL query to get data from one table based on condition I mentioned in the question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
equipment_type  machine_num status    datestamp
   RR               1         9      2021-08-20 10:39:36.430
   RR               2         1      2021-08-20 10:39:36.430
   RL               4         2      2021-08-20 10:39:36.700
   RR               5         0      2021-08-20 10:39:36.830
   RL               3         2      2021-08-20 10:39:37.030
   RR               1         3      2021-08-20 10:40:36.203
   RR               2         2      2021-08-20 10:40:36.207
   RL               4         1      2021-08-20 10:40:37.010
   RR               5         3      2021-08-20 10:40:37.200
   RL               3         3      2021-08-20 10:40:37.517
   RR               1         1      2021-08-20 10:40:38.203
   RR               2         1      2021-08-20 10:40:38.777
   RL               4         1      2021-08-20 10:40:39.010
   RR               5         1      2021-08-20 10:40:39.200
   RL               3         1      2021-08-20 10:40:39.517
```

There are 2 equipment types, 5 machine nums, 5 statuses and their respective datestamp in the table. If status shows 0 or 9 or 2 for particular equipment type(example:RR) and machine number(example:2) then I want that respective datestamp as starttime. After that starttime whenever the status shows 3 or 1 for same equipment type(example:RR) and machine num(example:2) then I want that respective time as endtime. After finds the endtime for equipment type(example:RR) and machine num(example:2) query should search for next starttime and endtime for that particular equipment type and machine num. This process is same for all machine num and their equipment type.

I want the output like below

```
equipment_type  machine_num   datestamp(start time)    endtime
   RR             1         2021-08-20 10:39:36.430  2021-08-20 10:40:36.203
   RR             2         2021-08-20 10:40:36.207  2021-08-20 10:40:38.777
   RL             4         2021-08-20 10:39:36.700  2021-08-20 10:40:37.010
   RR             5         2021-08-20 10:39:36.830  2021-08-20 10:40:37.200
   RL             3         2021-08-20 10:39:37.030  2021-08-20 10:40:37.517
```

Can anyone help me to write query for this? I badly need it.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68861781/sql-query-to-convert-one-column-into-two-based-on-three-different-column-values. Any difference at all?

Comment: I had asked the question more clearly

Comment: If you want to clarify the question, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68861781/edit) feature, @MariappanGanesan .

Comment: I had done it. But i didn't get the answer that's why I created another question